# Get all data from text file, would storing it in an array be the correct method?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

What I have is a program that will read the contents of a text file that reads

`FootballTeamName1 : FootballTeamName2 : FootballTeam1Score : FootballTeam2Score`

What I want to do is record each time that a team's name is mentioned.

So say if Liverpool is in it three times then it will be recorded that they play three games and note how many goals they scored then it will go the next team.

So if it was Manchester city then it will record the number of games they played along with the goals they scored as well as if they won the game etc. I also want to make it so that if Liverpool comes up again rather than create a new item it will add that to the original Liverpool mention rather than creating a duplicate value.

What I want to know is if an array is what I would use for this?

Comment: An array is far from ideal; use a `List`, and create a class for a team.

Comment: No. You'd probably better use a `Map<String, FootballTeamInformation>`, where the key is the football team name, and the value is an object containing all the information about that team. Read the tutorial on Java collections: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/.

Comment: @fge So say I made a map or a list how would I go about it making it so that say if the first item in the list is Fulham then it will create a new item in it and then if the next item is Leeds it will create a new one for them. Also how does this ensure that if Leeds is in the file again then it will add on to the values that were already in the list rather than add a new list item?

Comment: @Chris Martin: In your program, check if the team exists before you create the team class instance.  If it does, update the existing team class instance.  If it doesn't, create a new team class instance.